# Is it Safe? Storing database access method in library

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

First, I have two project working on: ASP.NET and Silverlight
Both uses a class (QueryServiceClass in a library class project) that have query methods to access the database with ADO.NET, manipulating the database. (open connection to database, add customer, edit, update etc.)

So I stored them into a C# Class library and it shared with ASP.Net and Silverlight.
ASP.NET project and Silverlight's Web project  will have a reference to the QueryServiceClass project.

But then if I publish the ASP.NET/Silverlight Project, the QueryServiceClass project's dll file should also be published ( the dll should be locate in the server side at this point).

Because the QueryServiceClass's method has to be public so ASP.NET/Silverlight project can use it.
So someone might able to use that dll to access the database? Would that be safe?

======
Edit

In the Silverlight's Web Project, I am using WCF inhert the QueryServiceClass and an Interface to access the database, so on Silverlight Client, it will access the database through the WCF.
I am more concern on someone might take the dll file from the server and give to someone.

Thanks in advance.

King

Comment: If the database stores any personal identification information, if the dll was in the wrong hands, anyone could access your database.  You can take that comment for what you feel its worth.

Comment: Just for clarification, will your Silverlight thing be accessing the database directly? In other words, will the client have access to your connection string?

Comment: No, Silverlight Client it will need to go through WCF, WCF is the only project that will reference that QueryService dll file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your members internal instead of public and modify the AssemblyInfo.cs class and make internals visible to specific asseblies.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("OtherLib.Domain.Stuff")]
```

This doesn't keep someone from disassembling your DLL to get the info, but will keep people from using your dll in their code.

Comment: This is a good solution if you have some level of trust with the end user - but they could still decompile or use reflection to get the details they want.

Comment: Correction, this is a good solution if and only if you absolutely trust your end users not to try to mess with your database.

Comment: But if we talk about decompile, would that be the same if I just have all my database access code inside my WCF?

Answer (score 1):

Public or not, **that will not be safe**. If your thing accesses a database without proper access restrictions, in *any* way, from a non-trustworthy computer, your database will be wide open.

The correct way to do this is to put a web service between your Silverlight thing and the database and do *thorough* access checks in the service.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the safest way to prevent any issue is to not allow remote access to your database from the public internet. This is usually handled by having a service run on a web server (the service could be a website) and then connecting to the database with the service. Basically, you should ensure that no connections can be made directly to the database server from a machine outside of your network.

Comment: Oh, so is like WCF is locate inside the Server so is local connection to the database. While when we use Silverlight is connecting to WCF with external connection.

Comment: The basic network layout is that you have firewalls that allow port 80 (and possibly 443) through to the web servers, so that web traffic can get through, but whatever port your database is listening on is blocked by the firewall. Since your web server is already behind the firewall, it can communicate to the database server. This is an extremely simple example, but it solves the security issue. Your Silverlight app should talk to a service, it should *not* directly connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this safe by storing your DB login credentials in a config file and encrypting them. Then they could access the dll, but without valid credentials could not connect to the DB.

Here's [an article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx) that describes encrypting values in a web.config file.

Edit: Combine this with Chris's suggestion, and you have a good, secure solution.

Comment: No. Encrypting a connection string does not protect against malicious users.

Comment: Yes. It does, and if you think it doesn't, provide a reason.

Comment: Because at some point the connection string will have to be decrypted in order to connect, and if the decryption can take place on a non-trusted machine, the connection string can be retrieved.

Comment: And your solution of putting a web service wrapper around it is subject to the same failing. The assembly which connects to the DB is still sitting behind the service. If a malicious user gets access to that assembly, they can also get the connection string. It all comes down to the security paradox that to let some people into a system, you risk leaving holes that will let anyone who knows how to exploit them in. At least with an encrypted connection string, you add another layer of protection.

Comment: Nothing is 100% secure, but I would definitely agree with Craig M that encrypting the connection string is certainly a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you made the methods private, they could use reflection or decompile the DLL to get your code and then access the database.

- You could have a WCF service which does all DB interactions and the client connects through the service. This way a direct connection can't be made but methods could still be called if the end user can determine the location and authentication scheme, etc., of your WCF service.
- You could just store and encrypt the connection info the config file.